# Combining data from two tables within ranges - SQL

Tags: sql

Hi so i'm trying to answer the question 'Is our evaluation system helping to develop employees.' Currently the two tables i refer from are Evaluation and Employees whereby each has an evaluation score (Evaluations), promotion_last_5years (0/1)(Employees) and satisfaction (Employees).
So far i have three queries

1. Output number of employees in 4 evaluation score brackets
2. Output average satisfaction of employees in each bracket
3. Output counts of those promoted in each bracket

1)

```
SELECT e.range AS [0-1], count(*) AS [Number of Employees]
FROM 
(
  SELECT (CASE WHEN score BETWEEN 0 AND 0.25 THEN '0-0.25'
               WHEN score BETWEEN 0.25 AND 0.5 THEN '0.25-0.5'
               WHEN score BETWEEN 0.5 AND 0.75 THEN '0.5-0.75'
               WHEN score BETWEEN 0.75 AND 1 THEN '0.75-1'
          END) as range
  FROM Evaluation
) e
GROUP BY e.range;
```

2)

```
SELECT AVG(satisfaction)
FROM Employee
WHERE score IN (SELECT score FROM Evaluation WHERE score>0 AND score<0.25);
```

3)

```
SELECT promotion_last_5years, count(*) AS Proportion_promoted
FROM Employee
WHERE score IN (SELECT score FROM Evaluation WHERE score>0 AND score<0.25)
GROUP BY promotion_last_5years;
```

OR

```
SELECT TotPromoted/TotalNotPromoted
FROM 
(
    SELECT count(*) AS TotPromoted 
    FROM Employee 
    WHERE promotion_last_5years='1' AND score IN 
    (
        SELECT score FROM Evaluations WHERE score>0 AND score<0.25
    );
),

(SELECT count(*) AS TotalNotPromoted 
FROM Employee 
WHERE promotion_last_5years='0' AND score IN (SELECT score FROM Evaluations WHERE score>0 AND score<0.25);)
```

So on so forth for remaining ranges

I ask you is there any way to combine the data from these queries into one single table? If so please enlighten me as i am an SQL beginner. Also i am open to any other suggestions regarding how i ought to go about answering this question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. First there is a table `evaluation` with a `score` and it seems the records contain employees, because you count and call the result "Number of Employees". Anyway, there is also a table called `employee`, also with a `score`. Why two tables? What is the difference between the tables? Then, isn't `WHERE score IN (SELECT score FROM Employee WHERE score>0 AND score<0.25)` simply `WHERE score > 0 AND score < 0.25`? Please show sample results for the queries and what the final result shall look like.

Comment: Combine how? Show us sample results for the queries, and how they end up combined. As formatted text, not images.

Comment: I'm outputting information for 4 ranges of evaluation score between 0 and 1. The second score is satisfaction. Essentially i am trying to have data from within each range. The ranges however are in the evaluation table and i will need to take information from my employee table to output promotions and satisfaction scores. Currently we are still building the database fully so i can't put results of the query.

Comment: My goal is to have 4 rows, one with each range followed by the required data in each      i.e: 0-0.25 | "X Number of Employees" | Satisfaction | Proportion of promoted

Comment: Now looking back though i see that i will need to put the proportion instead of grouping by promoted/not

Comment: Still though the question remains, how do i take these three separate queries and merge them into one table

Comment: Maybe SELECT TotPromoted/TotalNotPromoted
FROM (SELECT count(*) AS TotPromoted FROM Employee WHERE promotion_last_5years='1' AND score IN (SELECT score FROM Evaluations WHERE score>0 AND score<0.25);),
(SELECT count(*) AS TotalNotPromoted FROM Employee WHERE promotion_last_5years='0' AND score IN (SELECT score FROM Evaluations WHERE score>0 AND score<0.25);)